# Using integral test for convergence of $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac 1 {n^3}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, definite-integrals

How do I show that the series 
$\:\large\sum_\limits{n=1}^{\infty}\large{\frac 1 {\:n^3}}\:$
is convergent using the integral test ?

Comment: For starters, do you know the statement of the integral test?

Comment: yes, however in the examples given the power when the function is changed from a function of k to a function of x is changed which confuses me

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include your understanding of the integral test? I'm not quite sure what you mean.

Comment: @MathFreak Please don't edit questions to include large in titles - it takes up too much space (also, drastically changing the notation to $\mathbb{N}$ doesn't go well with the original question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here $f(n)=\frac{1}{n^3}$ so $f(x)=\frac{1}{x^3}$. Then for $N\in \mathbb N$ $$\int_{1}^{N}\frac{1}{x^3}\,dx=\left[-\frac{1}{2x^2}\right]^{N}_1=\frac12-\frac{1}{2N^2}\to \frac12$$ as $N\to \infty$.

Answer (score 4):

An alternative to the integral test is the technique called "creative telescoping":

$$\begin{eqnarray*} \color{red}{\zeta(3)} = 1+\sum_{n\geq 2}\frac{1}{n^3}&\color{red}{\leq}& 1+\sum_{n\geq 2}\frac{1}{(n-1)n(n+1)}\\&=&1+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n\geq 2}\left(\frac{1}{n-1}-\frac{2}{n}+\frac{1}{n+1}\right)\\&=&1+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n\geq 2}\left(\frac{1}{n-1}-\frac{1}{n}\right)-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n\geq 2}\left(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}\right)\\&=&1+\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{4}=\color{red}{\frac{5}{4}}.\end{eqnarray*} $$

The bound is quite tight and the technique can be generalized in order to prove Apery's identity:
$$ \zeta(3) = \frac{5}{2}\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^3\binom{2n}{n}}. $$

Comment: Nice way of showing upper bound! +1

Answer (score 3):

$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac 1 {n^3}
= 1 + \sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac 1 {n^3}
\le 1 + \sum_{n=2}^\infty \int_{n-1}^n \frac 1 {x^3}\,dx
= 1 + \int_1^\infty \frac 1 {x^3} \, dx = 1 + \frac 1 2.  
$$

Answer (score 2):

By [Integral test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence),

we have $$\int_N^\infty \frac{1}{n^3} dn = \left[-\frac{1}{2n^2}\right]_N^\infty=\frac{1}{2N^2}$$ and this improper integral quite evidently exists. Hence the series is convergent.